# Restrict usser from using spacebars in batch program

Tags: batch-file, set, delimiter

Im ussing the following which works fine for my needs except I want to restrict the user from entering any spacebars how can I do this?

```
SET /P GET_ADMIN_PASSWORD_MISSMATCH_OPTION= Selection:
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't restrict them from pressing space in batch, but you can get rid of the spaces after they have entered something

```
set /p GET_ADMIN_PASSWORD_MISSMATCH_OPTION=Selection: 
set GET_ADMIN_PASSWORD_MISSMATCH_OPTION=%GET_ADMIN_PASSWORD_MISSMATCH_OPTION: =%
```

I would also suggest using shorter variable names! :)

Comment: You should first warn users that spaces are not acceptable, then verify that the shortened password is what they wanted. But otherwise just what I was going to say.